# How do I connect to ActiveMQ Artemis embedded server?

Tags: activemq-artemis, embedded-server

I have an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis application that I have started using below configuration & code:

`broker.xml`

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:activemq"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

        <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
        <paging-directory>target/data/paging</paging-directory>
        <bindings-directory>target/data/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>target/data/journal</journal-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>target/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
       
        <acceptors>

            <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                <permission type="manage" roles="guest"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>

        <address-settings>
            ...
        </address-settings>

        <addresses>
            ...
        </addresses>

    </core>
</configuration>
```

jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory=vm://0
```

`Main.java`

```java
SecurityConfiguration securityConfig = new SecurityConfiguration();
securityConfig.addUser("guest", "guest");
securityConfig.addRole("guest", "guest");
securityConfig.setDefaultUser("guest");
ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager securityManager = new ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager(InVMLoginModule.class.getName(), securityConfig);

// Step 2. Create and start embedded broker.
server = ActiveMQServers.newActiveMQServer("broker.xml", null, securityManager);
server.start();
```

I have few application that produce messages and consume messages. How do I configuration these application so that they communicate with the embedded server to produce and consume message. When I use `tcp://localhost:61616` as broker URL, I am not able to connect to the embedded server. What configuration changes should I make in order to achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only `acceptor` you have:

```xml
<acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
```

Therefore this is the only URL you can use from your clients: `vm://0`.

If you want to connect to `tcp://localhost:61616` then you need to configure a corresponding `acceptor`, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="activemq">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>
```

Comment: I must have been confused with acceptor and connector. I was trying to add same configuration for connector. Thank you so much for pointing out. It worked. :)